# Discover an index "nulls first|last" from DatabaseMetaData.getIndexInfo() for Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to get information about whether an index has been defined with "nulls last" or "nulls first" from the metadata?

Comment: The jdbc docs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html?is-external=true#getIndexInfo-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-boolean-) doesn't seem to specify such information is available. Maybe through a postgres-specific api call?

Comment: `pg_indexes.indexdef` contains that information - but that's the complete index definition

Comment: Yes, the information can be had from the database-specific implementations (as with PG), but i do not believe there is a "standardized" implementation through JDBC indeed. At least, i still cannot find it.